# Как переключать дату свайпами?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Мне необходимо реализовать переключение между датами, используя свайпы: свайп влево - следующий день, вправо - предыдущий. И для каждой даты будут отображаться свои данные из базы данных. Как реализовать это? Пробую сделать это при помощи `ViewPager`, но как создать в нём неограниченное количество элементов?

[image: моё приложение]

Comment: Попробуйте эту либу https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

Comment: у вас есть кол-во дат? я могу сделать вам такой адаптер по быстрому, и либы здесь никакие не нужны, и ViewPager по сути нормально подходит

Comment: Даты не ограничены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хмм, ну `ViewPager`'ом реализовывать *swipe* - это как из пушки по воробьям...

Лучше уж нормально детектировать `Gesture` или если уж совсем лень, то применить либу [swipe](https://github.com/pwittchen/swipe) и писать что-то типа:

```
swipe = new Swipe();
  swipe.addListener(new SwipeListener() {
    @Override public void onSwipingLeft(final MotionEvent event) {
      //SWIPING_LEFT
    }

    @Override public void onSwipedLeft(final MotionEvent event) {
      // SWIPED_LEFT
    }

    @Override public void onSwipingRight(final MotionEvent event) {
      //SWIPING_RIGHT
    }

    @Override public void onSwipedRight(final MotionEvent event) {
      //SWIPED_RIGHT
    }
  });
}
```